# &#xC3; &#xA9; and other codes

Tags: utf-8, utf8-decode

I got a file full of those codes, and I want to "translate" it into normal chars (a whole file, I mean). How can I do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What do you see when you open the file in a hex editor?

Comment: Sorry about my bad explanation. I mean, with utf8_decode() function of PHP I can show the real value, but I need to change that to the whole file. How to do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like you originally had a UTF-8 file which has been interpreted as an 8 bit encoding (e.g. [ISO-8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)) and entity-encoded. I say this because the sequence C3A9 looks like a pretty plausible [UTF-8 encoding sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

You will need to first entity-decode it, then you'll have a UTF-8 encoding again. You could then use something like [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.1.html) to convert to an encoding of your choosing.

To work through your example:

- &#xC3; &#xA9; would be decoded as the byte sequence 0xC3A9
- 0xC3A9 = 11000011 10101001 in binary
- the leading 110 in the first octet tells us this could be interpreted as a UTF-8 two byte sequence. As the second octet starts with 10, we're looking at something we can interpret as UTF-8. To do that, we take the last 5 bits of the first octet, and the last 6 bits of the second octet...
- So, interpreted as UTF8 it's 00011101001 = E9 = é ([LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm))

You mention wanting to handle this with PHP, something like this might do it for you:

```
 //to load from a file, use
 //$file=file_get_contents("/path/to/filename.txt");
 //example below uses a literal string to demonstrate technique...

 $file="&Pr&#xC3;&#xA9;c&#xC3;&#xA9;dent is a French word";
 $utf8=html_entity_decode($file);
 $iso8859=utf8_decode($utf8);

 //$utf8 contains "Précédent is a French word" in UTF-8
 //$iso8859 contains "Précédent is a French word" in ISO-8859
```

Comment: But how to change a whole file? I mean, it's a file with "common" text and encoded sequences...

Comment: If this technique doesn't work for your file, I'd suggest including a small hex dump of a relevant sample of your file.

Comment: For instance: Pr&#xC3;&#xA9;c&#xC3;&#xA9;dent (it's a French word). In the file, there exists words without accents, but others with (and that's the issue, I need to convert those accent words into, at least, UTF8, and then I'd likely use iconv or something like).

Comment: The result of html_entity_decode() on the string you provided is the UTF-8 encoding of Précédent - not sure I see the problem.

Comment: Let me put it another way: decode the whole file, and update your question with exactly what's wrong when you decode with html_entity_decode. If you're not sure how to load a file into a string, try $str=file_get_contents($my_filename)

Comment: Well, really that's a silly problem. Your question was very nice, thank you very much!