# URLs with file names having accented characters

Tags: php, mysql, apache2.2

In one of my PHP based websites, I have a script which will display an image from a CentOS server. Image path is taken from MySQL database. Image files stored on the server (and corresponding entries in the database) are having accented characters and spaces in it.

So when the PHP script tries to access the image URL, it returns a file not found error. When I checked apache error logs, I could see that the accented characters in file names are shown like "2-EDUCACI\xc3\x93N SECUNDARIA-ACTIVIDAD ACAD\xc3\x89MICA-VIAJE FIN DE CURSO (1).jpg" (an example of image name "2-EDUCACIÓN SECUNDARIA-ACTIVIDAD ACADÉMICA-VIAJE FIN DE CURSO (1).jpg")

If I try to get file listing through shell with real file name given inside quotes, I can get the listing.  But if I try without giving any file name, the list is shown with ? marks instead of accented characters in file names.

Can you please give me some guidance on solving this file not found issue.  I am looking for a solution involving either changing something in PHP code, or in the server itself? I have root access to the server.

I already came across some similar questions and answers on web, but those are referring to changing the encoding of file name on server (like using utilities like convmv, etc). But in my case, I am not in a position to change the file names or encoding. These files are uploaded by customers from their local system and thus I cannot insist them to use a specific naming convention or file name encoding. What I am looking for is a possibility to attain this through some PHP functions, or apache configurations.

Any inputs regarding this is highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Sujith

Comment: If you don't have consistent encoding of text stored on your server (in this case the file name), you will have a real problem.  You may want to check at time of upload if the encoding is that preferred by your environment (e.g. UTF-8) and if not, change the file name encoding right after upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have inconsistent character encoding at some point during your process, and your data is returning 8 bit encoded. You will have to entity decode and re-encode it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177783/xc3-xa9-and-other-codes#answer-4177813) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input.  I created a PHP script through which I converted the file names. I used the iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", "$fileName") to change the characters in file names to its ASCII equivalent and set this script in a cron job. So, even if customer add new files with accents, it will get replaced when the cron task is executed.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Have experienced this problems, just use the iconv fonction like this:

```
echo iconv("ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", "UTF-8", $lien);
```